# T-SQL Update Query syntax error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this simple query :-

```
update [Schema1].ReportData 
set Qry = 'declare @cols nvarchar(max) select @cols = ''Code,Name,DateOfJoining''' 
where ViewName = 'Rpt1'
```

But here is the problem. I have more than 50 schemas, so I did the following
(summarized SQL):

```
WHILE (@i <= (SELECT MAX(idx) FROM @schema_table))
    BEGIN

        -- get the next record primary key
        SET @schema_names = (SELECT schema_names FROM @schema_table WHERE idx = @i)

        BEGIN TRY
            DECLARE @sSQL nvarchar(500);            
            SELECT @sSQL = N'update '+@schema_names+'.ReportData set Qry='declare @cols nvarchar(max) select @cols = ''Code,FName,DateOfJoining ,CategoryName''' where  ViewName='Rpt1''
            EXEC sp_executesql @sSQL
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE()+' '+@schema_names AS ErrorMessage;
        END CATCH

        -- increment counter for next record
        SET @i = @i + 1
    END
```

But is giving me syntax error on this line :-

```
SELECT @sSQL = N'update '+@schema_names+'.ReportData set Qry='declare @cols nvarchar(max) select @cols = ''Code,FName,DateOfJoining ,CategoryName''' where  ViewName='Rpt1''
```

Actually i tried many things like using double quotes & escape characters. 
How to solve this?

Comment: change to: PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE()+' '+@schema_names AS ErrorMessage;? Problem is still avaiable?

Comment: @starko I didn't get you?

Comment: You UPDATE is messed up, what are you trying to do?

Comment: Tried to make this syntax work, but the whole thing you're doing selecting that value for `@cols` you really should clarify that.

Comment: I am saving the queries in the database for my application & `Qry` is the column in which i save the queries.

Answer (score 1):

Hope that I understood your UPDATE statement right:

```
SELECT @sSQL = N'update '+QUOTENAME(@schema_names)+'.ReportData 
set Qry=''declare @cols nvarchar(max) select @cols = ''''Code,FName,DateOfJoining ,CategoryName''''''
where  ViewName=''Rpt1'''
```

If you are working with any DB object it is better to use [QUOTENAME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx)

> Returns a Unicode string with the delimiters added to make the input string a valid SQL Server delimited identifier.

Will bring you this query to execute:

```
update [Schema1].ReportData 
set Qry='declare @cols nvarchar(max) select @cols = ''Code,FName,DateOfJoining ,CategoryName'''
where  ViewName='Rpt1'
```

So after running this batch, `Qry` will be equal to this:

```
declare @cols nvarchar(max) select @cols = 'Code,FName,DateOfJoining ,CategoryName'
```

**EDIT**

One more way is to use `CHAR(39)` (single quote):

```
SELECT @sSQL = N'update '+QUOTENAME(@schema_names)+'.ReportData 
set Qry= '+CHAR(39) +'declare @cols nvarchar(max) select @cols = '+CHAR(39)+ CHAR(39)+'Code,FName,DateOfJoining ,CategoryName'+ CHAR(39) +CHAR(39) + CHAR(39) + '
where  ViewName='+ CHAR(39)+'Rpt1'+ CHAR(39)
```

Comment: Same implementation as what I had, but I commend the good use of `QUOTENAME()`.

Comment: I tried both the examples. but still getting Unclosed Quotation mark error.

Comment: `Unclosed quotation mark after the character string `.. what string exactly? Please elaborate. Maybe you already got `[]` on the beginning/end of your schema names?

Comment: Maybe you got quotes in schema names? Can you check this?